# Delete rows with certain number in text string in a cell

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have a list with about 500 data entries and some of them have different text with the same number in a cell. I need to find all those rows with "00000" in it and delete them.
I need to calculate the time when "test2" startet no working(18:23) and need to know how long it took that it worked again(18:30) and the error00000 message is messing my formulas up so i need to delete all rows with error00000 in it. the error messege is never the same but "000000" in it is always the same.

I don't know how to find it with VBA code because I only can find numbers alone in cells. The data entries can change per week so it should be with VBA.
I have some code but its online working when the number is alone in a cell and not in a sentence like `Error message 00000` the text is always changing, the number stays the same.

My code for deleting rows with numbers alone in a cell

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim iCntr As Long
    lRow = 1000
    For iCntr = lRow To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(iCntr, 5).Value = "1008" Then
            Rows(iCntr).Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub



03.09.2015 18:30    test2   EXAMPLETEXT blablablalb error000002
03.09.2015 18:25    test2   EXAMPLETEXT blablablalb error000000
03.09.2015 18:23    test2   EXAMPLETEXT blablablalb error000002
03.09.2015 18:30    test1   EXAMPLETEXT blablablalb error000002
03.09.2015 18:25    test1   EXAMPLETEXT blablablalb error000000
03.09.2015 18:23    test1   EXAMPLETEXT blablablalb error000002
```

Comment: I already answered a similar question few days ago. Please search stackoverflow

Comment: And [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631363/how-to-copy-a-line-in-excel-using-a-specific-word-and-pasting-to-another-excel-s) is link to a very old question. Here I am copying the result to another sheet. You can simply delete that range.

Comment: Siddharth Routh in your answers but i dind't find any question which has anything to do with mine... 

And what has "How to copy a line in excel using a specific word and pasting to another excel sheet?" to do with "Delete rows with certain number in text string in a cell" ?

Comment: Please re-read my last comment again :)

Comment: oh sorry, my english is not the best. i missed that.. I still don't get the code. i don't understand it

What do i have to use? i need to find 0000000 in a cell with text

The text can change so i tried "*000000*" which clearly isn't working...

could this even work with my kind of code?

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot of your data. Add it to any file uploading site and share the link here

Comment: I postet an example i can't uploud any of my table because of data protection.

i have more collums but that shoudn't matter.


the "macro" should delete all rows with 000000 in the text in the third row ):

Comment: I just tested the code with your data and it works

Comment: I to bad in VBA coding that i know which code i have to use ehen i don't want the copy stuff.... can you tell me that please?

Comment: Please update the question with the autofilter code that you are trying

Comment: I updated kinda everything..

Comment: I don't see the autofilter code in your question?

Comment: What do you mean with autofiller code?

Comment: Sigh... Nothing... I will let @Zeeshan help you out :)

Comment: oh ok, but thank you very much for not giving up that fast with me!
I would give you a like or something but i can't
thank you really much!

Comment: I wouldn't have given up (I rarely give up) if you would "Listen" to me... Guess I got tired "repeating" myself :)

Comment: I didin't know what you have ment up there sorry, my english not my motherlanguage uts hard to work with words like codingstuff an so on

Comment: That is ok. I will visit this thread after couple of hours. If it is still not sorted then I will jump in...

Comment: hey @SiddharthRout can you help me?
the code from  isn'T working ): need help please

Comment: ok. can you do me a favor. Can you update your exact request in the question above. I don't want to read all those comments again. In your question ENSURE that you explain what do you want in details and then I will surely help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the below code to delete filtered rows. Before you run the code, make sure you enter values for the variables `strSearch`, `strSearchColName` and `strSheetName`.

```
Sub Delete_Rows_Condtionally()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim currentRow As Long
    Dim cellText As String
    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim strSearchColName As String

    strSearch = "000000"
    strSearchColName = "E"
    strSheetName = "tabelle2"

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(strSheetName)

        'Get last row
        lastRow = .Range(strSearchColName & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        currentRow = lastRow
        Do While currentRow >= 1
            cellText = .Range(strSearchColName & currentRow).Text
            If (InStr(1, cellText, strSearch)) Then
                .Range(strSearchColName & currentRow).EntireRow.Delete
            Else
                currentRow = currentRow - 1
            End If
        Loop

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What makes you think this is a duplicate? If some part of it was already answered elsewhere, it doesn't mean the entire question is duplicate.

Comment: "Some Part"? The linked question has all the code the OP needs and has to just change one line in that

Comment: I'm sure you could have answered it then.

Comment: Yes I could have but didn't as it is not ethical. And hence I gave a link to OP. If you are planning to delete the question then I will reverse the downvote :)

Comment: That doesn't really help me, i need to know how i can delete the rows with "000000" in a text. I can't filter it to delete rows because there are formulas which are calculating stuff in the table...

Comment: @Swi - How does filtering affect the formula calculations? They should work regardless if you filter or not. If you follow Siddharth's example, you can filter for `*000000*` and then delete the visible cells in your range. Then remove the filter. At worse, you have to modify is exact code a bit to fit your specific needs. But what you have all you need there - and more :)

Comment: I would be really happy if you answer my question because i don't know how to work with the link you gave me

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I have over 500 data entries with a lot of collums my code up there is deleteing all rows with specifig numbers(not only one like shown up there) so that only rows with 3 specifing numbers stay. then I#m sorting the rows acording to a type and then i'm calculating the time how long the dates are apart. The rows with "000000" in the text are  messing everything up. so i have to get them away.

Comment: @swi - have you even tried to work with any of the code posted - this answer or Siddharth's link? Have you tried to study the concepts and apply them to your problem?

Comment: @Scott yes. but i don't know which part i need beacause i don't need the copy stuff.

Comment: @SiddharthRout The code has been updated as per new requirements which do not want the data to be filtered. It is no longer a duplicate question nor a duplicate answer. Please undo the downvote as that would be the ethical thing to do.

Comment: With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(strSheetName)

what do ihave to put in there? 
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(strtabelle2)

my sheet is called tabelle2?

Comment: @Swi Modify only the assignment of the variables: strSearch = "000000"
    strSearchColName = "E"
    strSheetName = "Sheet1"
Leave the rest as is and run. In this case, strSheetName = "tabelle2"

Comment: it stops working there....

i put it in a commandbutton, could this be the problem?

Comment: Leave 'With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(strSheetName)' as is. Do not modify that. Modify only the variable assignments 'strSearch', 'strSearchColName' and 'strSheetName'.

Comment: What is the column name in which all the 'error000000' strings are entered?

Comment: strSearch = "00000000"
    strSearchColName = "J"
    strSheetName = "tabelle2"




it stops working there
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(strSheetName)

Comment: Update the question details section with a screenshot of your data set. The first 10 rows and the column in which the string is to be searched should be visible in the screenshot.

Comment: i can't, i already said why.
it tells me runtime error, always

Comment: Are you running the above code as a sub-part? Is any other VBA interfering with this code? 
The code I provided is working flawlessly on the sample data provided by you.
Due to lack of accurate information I'm not sure how to further debug your problem.

Comment: no there only is this code, 

It stops there "With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(strSheetName)" when i say debug